# Unable to rename computer with powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012-r2

```
$script = { Rename-Computer -ComputerName "ADMINIS-ID1PS7V" -NewName "SERVER1" }
$computerName = "ADMINIS-ID1PS7V"
$username = "Administrator"
$pw = "123!@#qaZ"

# Create Credentials
$securepw = ConvertTo-SecureString $pw -asplaintext -force
$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argument $username, $securepw

# Create and use session
$session = New-PSSession -credential $cred -ComputerName $computerName
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock $script
Remove-PSSession $session
```

- I disabled the firewall on the machine.
- I ran `enable-PSRemoting -force`
- I even set the GPO with `Allow remote server management through
  WinRM` to enabled with *

I keep getting:

```
Fail to rename computer 'ADMINIS-ID1PS7V' to 'SERVER1' due to the following exception: Access is denied.
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (ADMINIS-ID1PS7V:String) [Rename-Computer], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : FailToRenameComputer,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RenameComputerCommand
    + PSComputerName        : ADMINIS-ID1PS7V
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are you remoting (invoke-command) to use a cmdlet which has a -computername parameter?  Have you tried running the command directly?

Comment: That worked. Silly me. Not sure why I was using that on invoke. I just was thinking anything having to be done remotely needed to be in the invoke when invoke is for executing commands locally. If I am correct?

Comment: Generally, you don't use remoting with cmdlets that include a -computername parameter.  To do that you'd need to double-hop, which is not enabled by default.